# What negative Gate to Source threshold voltage means in MOSFET datasheet?

Tags: mosfet, datasheet, mosfet-driver

I have seen certain MOSFET data sheets with a negative threshold voltage, like:

- [Si2301DS](http://www.vishay.com/docs/70627/70627.pdf) Gate-Threshold Voltage \$V_{GS(th)}\$ = -0.45 V
- [AO4425](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO4425.pdf) Gate-Threshold Voltage \$V_{GS(th)}\$ = -3.5 V

Does it mean the MOSFETs are depletion type? Does it mean that if I do not apply any gate voltage and pull the gate to 0 or ground, they will still conduct until it is made below -3.5 V? Can someone please explain?

I am looking for MOSFETs that will switch off when Li-ion cell voltage reaches 3.3 V or lower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're PMOS. Vgs sign is opposite to NMOS.
For a PMOS to conduct, Vgs has to be negative... Simple as that...

> I am looking for MOSFETs that will switch off when Li-ion cell voltage reaches 3.3 V or lower.

You can get integrated LiIon protection chips to do that...

Comment: but TP4056 module has a cutoff voltage of 2.5 V.  I thought LI-Ion cells should not go below 3.5 V. TP4056 is the cheapest one. Do you have any other solution ?